# Thrift file how to define a list of object id

Tags: go, microservices, thrift

I am using thrift + Go, and my thrift file looks like this:

```
namespace go user

struct Role {
    1: string id;
    2: string roleName;
}

struct User {
    1: required string id;
    2: required string email;
    3: required string password;
    4: required string name;
    5: optional list<Role.id> roles;
}
```

when I run : `thrift -r --gen go user.thrift`

I got:
`Type "Role.id" not defined`

Any ideas on how I should achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Role.id is not a data type

```
struct User {
    1: required string id;
    2: required string email;
    3: required string password;
    4: required string name;
    5: optional list<string> roles;
}
```

Side notes:

- `set<string>` might be a better choice for roles ids
- regarding `required`: I strongly suggest to read [this comprehensive summary](https://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/) first, which has a whole section about that topic.